# Chrome Dev Tools in another tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How can i set **Chrome Dev Tools** as open a sibling tab.
I dont want at bottom or left of the page because of screen size while developing.
On the other hand there is a option as new page.

I searched forums and this site.
But couldnt find any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: why negative? what is the wrong with this question? i asked how can i open dev-tools in another tab. that'all.

Comment: Your question is probably being downvoted because it's not really a specific programming problem, but rather about how to use Chrome. You can detach the dev tools into a separate window, but I'm not sure if it's possible to put them into a tab. It *sounds like* you already know that, but maybe not...

Comment: Thanks, yes it can be in a seperated window. But my question is in fact can be a spesific programming problem. Because i thought maybe there is a regedit or devtools extension or config settings and so that asked.

Comment: Completely legit question, I would like to know the same. Having the dev tools in another tab would bring advantages, for instance fast navigation jump and thus easily comparing network loading.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get to what you want is to click on the little window icon on the top right and select floating mode to have your dev tools in a floating mode so that you can place it wherever you want.

Does this help?

[image: Image Showing options to have your dev tool window in floating and dock mode]

Comment: Thanks, yes i know this method but in this method screen size is halfing while designing layout. So that a new tab is may be a quick transition between layout design and code.